# grep ls output across tabs

Tags: bash, ls

If I `ls -l` in a directory and get:

```
-rwxr-x---  1 user1  admin        0  8 Aug  2012 file.txt
-rwxr-x---  1 user1  admin  1733480 26 Jul  2012 Archive.pax.gz
drwxr-x---@ 7 user1  admin      238 31 Jul  2012 Mac Shots
-rwxr-x---@ 1 user3  admin   598445 31 Jul  2012 Mac Shots.zip
-rwxr-x---@ 1 user1  admin      380  6 Jul  2012 an.sh
-rwxr-x---  1 user2  admin       14 30 Jun  2012 analystName.txt
-rwxr-x---  1 user1  admin       36  8 Aug  2012 apple.txt
drwxr-x---@ 7 user1  admin      238 31 Jul  2012 iPad Shots
-rwxr-x---@ 1 user1  admin  7372367 31 Jul  2012 iPad Shots.zip
-rwxr-x---  1 user2  admin      109 30 Jun  2012 test.txt
drwxr-x---  3 user1  admin      102 26 Jul  2012 usr
```

but want to list only the files owned by "user1" which were modified in "Aug" to get

```
-rwxr-x---  1 user1  admin        0  8 Aug  2012 file.txt
-rwxr-x---  1 user1  admin       36  8 Aug  2012 apple.txt
```

What is the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can be more explicit, since Michael's grep would also find a file owned by user1 namedd 'August iPad Shots' no matter when it was modified:

```
ls -l | awk '($3=="user1" && $7=="Aug")'
```

Comment: tested with a file named `file \n-rwxr-x---@ 1 user1  admin      380  6 Aug  2012 an.sh` (\n is a newline) and got an extra line in the output!

Answer (score 6):

Parsing `ls` output is never a good and reliable solution. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Instead, you can try :

```
find . -type f -user 'user1' -maxdepth 1
```

or

```
find . -type f -printf '%u %f\n' -maxdepth 1 # if you want to show the username
```

or

```
stat -c '%U %f' * | cut -d" " -f2-
```

See

```
man find
man stat
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Parsing `ls` is far too error-prone.  On the other hand, tools like `find` and `stat` were designed for exactly this sort of task.

Comment: GNU find has a `-printf` that offers stat-like output, so you can combine the two commands, too.

Comment: I understand the pitfalls of parsing `ls` and agree with script use but I'm just after a quick interactive method while trawling through log files where I am looking to filter for information from 2 field columns within the listing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the safest way to do it is like this :

```
touch --date "2012-08-01" /tmp/start
touch --date "2012-09-01" /tmp/stop
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -user user1 -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/stop -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l {}
rm /tmp/start /tmp/stop
```

Or as a *one liner*

```
touch --date "2012-08-01" /tmp/start; touch --date "2012-09-01" /tmp/stop; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -user user1 -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/stop -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l {}; rm /tmp/start /tmp/stop
```

Advantages:

- You [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- It works for filenames with *Aug* in them

Disadvantages

- It is a bit long

Explanation:

- *-maxdepth 1*: restricts the results to the current directory
- *-type f*: restricts the results to files
- *-user user1*: resttrings the results to files that belong to *user1*
- *-newer /tmp/start*: restring the results to files *newer* than `/tmp/start`, which was created with the desired date
- *-not -newer /tmp/stop*: restring the results to files *not newer* than `/tmp/stop`, which was created with the desired date
- *-print0*: so it can handle filenames with newlines in their name!

Answer (score 0):

How about `ls -l | grep user1 | grep Aug`?

Or you can combine the regexp: `ls -l | grep 'user1.*Aug'`

Comment: If you want to be more rigorous, use `find -user user1 ...`

Comment: Please complete that thought and make it a real answer. Parsing LS is [such a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that there are multiple blogs written about it, and as many StackOverflow answers say the same.